# How to use ngx-translate to translate component or service strings inside the typescript file

Tags: angular, internationalization, translation, ngx-translate

How to use ngx-translate to translate component or service strings in the typescript file?

For example if I need to return a translated validation error from my validation service, how to do that in the service itself instead of using:
`{{'errorCode' | translate}}` in the template file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using ngx-translate get method using the key value for the string to be translated (used in the translation json files):

```
 // in your validation_service.ts, where translate is ngx-translate obj
 constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {
  console.log('Called Constructor');
  translate.addLangs(['en', 'ar']);
  translate.setDefaultLang('en');
}
 getErrorMsg(errors) {
      if (errors.required) {
        // get translation of the error
        const requiredError: any = this.translate.get('requiredFieldError');
        // return the error to be displayed
        return requiredError.value;
    }
  }
```

Note:

I found some questions that answer this but I am rephrasing it as I couldn't find these questions easily (stackoverflow suggested these questions when I writing this one), so hopefully this can help someone facing similar issue.